# Send file from Action to Servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload

My goal is to upload a file from an action to a servlet.

Till now, I thought I had it working in this way:

- Action: reads file as bytearray, converts it into String and puts String on request

  ```
  HttpURLConnection conn =null;
   String url = "http://myServlet");
  URL obj = new URL(url);
   conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    StringBuffer requestParams = new StringBuffer();
    requestParams.append("fileString");
    requestParams.append("=").append(URLEncoder.encode(fileString, "ISO-8859-1"));
   //Append more params
   OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
   wr.write(requestParams.toString());
   wr.flush();
  conn.getContentLength();
  ```
- Servlet: get String parameter, converts it back to bytearray and re-creates the file

  ```
     receivedString = request.getParameter("fileString");
      //Convert to bytearray and create file
  ```

But I guess this isn't a good solution, cause sometimes the call just fails because of the string (length maybe?)

Which is the right way to send my file? I can't find a way to send the file AND additional informations putting them on the request.

Comment: Try in this way 1). pass the additional information as query string in the URL itself 2) use POST request instead of GET to send the actual file contents.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but still not working (If I got it right)